# Many to many field django add the relationship both way

Tags: python, django, database, many-to-many

I'm trying to do a function that allow a user to follow another one. the problem is when I'm adding a new user to the "followings" the user that follow another user is also added in the following list of the followed user. For example if user a follow user b I will have that:

**view.py**

```
def follow_test(request):
    name = request.POST.get('name', '')
    user_followed = Dater.objects.get(username=name)
    current_user = Dater.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    print "Current", current_user.followings.all() # display []
    print "Followed", user_followed.followings.all() # display []
    current_user.followings.add(user_followed)
    print "Current", current_user.followings.all() # display <Dater: b>
    print "Followed", user_followed.followings.all() # display <Dater: a>
```

**model.py**:

```
followings = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

I would like the user b only to be add in the followings of a

Comment: Could you please print the output too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, many-to-many relationships on self are symmetrical. If you don't want this, set `symmetrical` to False:

```
followings = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)

Answer (score 3):

Just set related_name="followed_by" for the many to many field. That would assign the reverse mapping to followed_by

```
followings = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='followed_by')
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the solution you are proposing. I do have to set my model?

Comment: Updated the answer with the Modified model field. Hope that helps. Lemme know if you have any other questions